# d3.nest() to convert csv to json

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I want to create a nested json file from a csv using d3.nest() however, I am having trouble getting the nesting right. My output looks like this:
[image]

Which is close but not quite- I would like the values to be 
key
values: 
    0: etc
    1: etc

Here is my code:

d3.csv("data/fifa-matches.csv", function(error, matchesCSV) {

```
    //Loads in the tree information from fifa-tree.csv and calls createTree(csvData) to render the tree.
    matchesCSV.forEach(function(d, i) {

        this.teamData = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.Team;
            })

        .rollup(function(d) {
                return {
                    Result: { 'Label': d.Result, 'Rank': 'test' },

                    // total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.amount; }),
                    // avg: d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.amount; })
                }
            })
            .entries(matchesCSV);
        console.log(this.teamData);
    });

    d3.csv("data/fifa-tree.csv", function(error, treeCSV) {

        //Create a unique "id" field for each game
        treeCSV.forEach(function(d, i) {
            //console.log(d);
            d.id = d.Team + d.Opponent + i;
            d.type = d.Type;


        });
```

Any info in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Here is an example of the structure of the csv:

Team,Opponent,Goals Made,Goals Conceded,Delta Goals,Wins,Losses,Result
Brazil,Germany,1,7,-6,0,1,Semi Finals
Germany,Argentina,1,0,1,1,0,Winner
Argentina,Netherlands,0,0,0,1,0,Semi Finals
Netherlands,Brazil,3,0,3,1,0,Fourth Place
Brazil,Colombia,2,1,1,1,0,Quarter Finals
France,Germany,0,1,-1,0,1,Quarter Finals

Comment: Please, explain better what your desired outcome is (preferably showing the exact structure of the array), right now it's not exactly clear. Also, please copy/paste a few rows of your CSV (with the header), so we can provide a **running** solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify what's in each of the objects that correspond to a key, you can use the `.rollup()` function

```
this.teamData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.Team;
    }).rollup(function(match_object) { 
        return {
            opponent: match_object[0]["Opponent"],
            Goals Made: match_object[0]["Goals Made"],
            ..etc...
}).entries(matchesCSV);
```

and to return an array from treeCSV

```
function ReturnTeam(teamname){
    for(team in treeCSV) {
        if(teamname === team.Name) {
            return team;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply- would match object be a separate object that would provide data or would I be able to pass 'd' through?

Comment: no problem :) `match_object` and `d` are different names for the same thing, i just thought `match_object` is more descriptive

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So The structure of the rollup it great but the values come back as undefined. Is something going wrong with how I am accessing the data during the rollup?

Comment: My bizzle, rollup returns an array.  Use  `teamData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.Team;
    }).rollup(function(match_object) { 
        // console.log(match_object);
        return {
            opponent: match_object[0]["Opponent",
            "Goals Made": match_object[0]["Goals Made"]
        };
}).entries(matchesCSV);`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! One more question and I have updated my question with my updated code- it is combining the treesCSV with the first data set. Ideally I would have the lower treesCSV data as an array in the this.teamData. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: That's doable, try using this function to return the array associated with the teamname, then add it during your rollup